# How to change a dynamically created element after it loads javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, callback

I have a site that makes an HTTP request for JSON data, then a callback function processes the data and displays it by creating a series of divs dynamically.  What I want to do is to wait for that function to finish adding the divs to the page, then apply labels only to specific divs created by the previous code.

**HTTP Request and Callback**

```
function data(callback){
    var url = //request url;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    document.body.className = 'ok';
                    //Parse returned string into an object, then pass the object to the callback function.
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    callback(data);
                } else {
                    document.body.className = 'error';
                }
            }
        };
    request.open("GET", url , true);
    request.send(null);
}
function dataDisplay(data){
    //outputs <div id="1064" class="displayed-data">
                  <p id="message1" class="hidden"></p>
}
data(dataDisplay);
```

The code above displays my data exactly how I want it to, but when I try to access the numbered ID of the divs I want to change, the function runs before the data is displayed on the page, causing a 'null' error because the data I am trying to change hasn't been added to the  DOM yet.

**Second Function to change original**

```
function label(){
    var message1 = document.createTextNode('//some label');
    var displayedData = document.getElementById('1064').getElementById('message1');
    displayedData.appendChild(message1);
    document.getElementById('message1').classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

How do I get the second function to wait until the callback has completed before trying to access and change it?  I tried a callback inside of a callback, something like: `label(data(dataDisplay));` but it still threw the same errors, so I clearly did it wrong.  Sorry, I am brand new to JavaScript and don't really know where to go from here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty quick way of doing it correctly is with this inline function.

```
data(function(result) {
  dataDisplay(result);
  label();
});
```

Be aware that your `data` function itself completes very quickly - if you need something from its result, you will need to include it in its callback.